# Why I can't reload apache2 on Ubuntu?

Tags: apache, virtualhost

On Ubuntu, each time I use `sudo service apache2 reload` command to reload apache2 service , my terminal showed

```
apache2.service is not active, cannot reload.
```

And, I'm trying to add phpMyAdmin as virtual host, using `phpmyadmin.local` as local-area-network domain name; can anyone tell me how? I have tried many times today, I searched many methods, but until now, it's still `404 not found`.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 16.04. This was causing problems with logrotate, because it could not reload Apache after rotating logs.

The full error I was getting:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
[....] Reloading apache2 configuration (via systemctl):    apache2.serviceapache2.service is not active, cannot reload.
 failed!
```

The problem went away after stopping Apache with apachectl and starting it with /etc/init.d/apache2:

```
apachectl stop
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

You can now reload Apache:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
[ ok ] Reloading apache2 configuration (via systemctl): apache2.service.
```

If you start Apache with `apachectl start`, it is not being marked as an active service, so you can't reload it with `service apache2 reload`. You have to start Apache with `/etc/init.d/apache2 start` or `service apache2 start`.

I'm not sure if it's intended or a bug. I can't reproduce this with an older system.

Comment: This solution worked for me as well, I'm still stumped as to the cause, and a little afraid of not knowing, but at least this is a fix.

Answer (score 16):

Actually you should check if another service/server is running in the port 80 :

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80
```

If it's not apache2, stop it (for me it was lighttpd so `sudo service lighttpd stop`.

Then start apache2 (`sudo service apache2 start`) and enjoy!

Comment: Great tip! Thanks this was exactly my issue, had some NGINX servers up and running :)

Comment: Life saver! How on earth and why would nginx run by itself!?

Comment: You are still saving life's in 2021 lol. Thanks bro for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

check if you are missing `/usr/sbin/apache2`
Then if you are run: `sudo apt install --reinstall apache2-bin`